# click event not working on new html with append , even using on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am creating a new element and child of that element with `beforesend` in Ajax.

Later on I want to show the child element if I click on its parent...

```
$('#submit-task').on('click', function() {
    // variable declarations etc
    jQuery.ajax({
        // other data
        beforeSend: function() {
            jQuery('#' + month + ' .month-tasks-design').append(
                '<div class="month-task" data-id="' + next_id + '" style="width:0%;background: ' + colour + ';"><div class="task-info">Name: ' + name + '<br />Design Hours: ' + design_hours + '<br />Description: ' + description + '<br /></div></div>');

            jQuery('#' + month + ' .month-tasks-dev').append(
                '<div class="month-task" data-id="' + next_id + '" style="width:0%;background: ' + colour + ';"><div class="task-info">Name: ' + name + '<br />Development Hours: ' + dev_hours + '<br />Description: ' + description + '<br /></div></div>');

            jQuery('.month-tasks-design div[data-id=' + next_id + ']').animate({ width: design_width + '%'}, 1000,  function() {});

            jQuery('.month-tasks-dev div[data-id=' + next_id + ']').animate({ width: dev_width + '%'}, 1000,  function() {});               


        },
        // other data

    }); 
});

$('.month-task').on('click', function(e) {
    if ( e.target !== this ) { return; }
    var task_info = $(this).find('.task-info');
    $(task_info).fadeIn(200);
});
```

however nothing happens when I click on `.month-task`, it does work however with page loaded html, just not with the newly generated html

Comment: Use like this  $(document).on('click','.month-task', function(e) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `event-delegation` at this context,

```
$(document).on('click','.month-task', function(e) {
    if ( e.target !== this ) { return; }
    var task_info = $(this).find('.task-info');
    $(task_info).fadeIn(200);
});
```

**Note :** In the place of document, you should use a static parent to the appended element.

Comment: Thank you that worked, I will accept answer in 10 mins

Comment: Just wondering what the difference between that and what I originally had is?

Comment: I mean in terms of why one works and the other doesnt

Comment: @Adrian While registering event, the element belongs to that selector would not be available in the dom. since you are appending it on the runtime. so at this context we have to use event-delegation. Event-delegion internally uses event bubbling to overcome the issue. please read [here](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the way to delegate , say like bellow

```
$(document).on('click', '.month-task', function(e) {
```